# Cisco AnyConnect Second Password option

Tags: vpn, cisco

I was running fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 with vpnc and its network manager to connect to my office cisco based VPN. Now they have implemented [Mobile Pass](http://www.safenet-inc.com/multi-factor-authentication/authenticators/software-authentication/mobilepass-otp-authenticator/) to authenticate with an additional Second Password (Generated by Mobile Pass App) along with the existing user password and I am left broken with no option to connect to my office Cisco VPN.

I tried Open Client for Cisco AnyConnect VPN and its manager framework on Ubuntu 14.04. But that too doesn’t provide any option for a second password.

The windows and Android based Cisco Anyconnect client provides these options by default. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have the entire stream from my Ubuntu laptop to connect to my work PC by way of Cisco AnyConnect.  I do have the VPN working, as when I enable the VPN connection I'm told that I'm connected.  What I'm working on is getting a VNC (Remmina) to actually connect with the remote Win7 PC.

My work network has the two-password bit enabled.  I'm able to enter both passwords.  I got to there on Ubuntu through the openconnect / network-manager-openvpn / network-manager-openvpn-gnome stack, along with whatever plugins the install requires.  I haven't (yet?) installed the official Cisco software.

Once you install the software and hard reboot your PC (things didn't work well with the "Reboot" option) you can create a VPN connection.  Once you try to login you're asked for a username, password, another username and another password.  I ignore the second username and things are working as I described earlier.

I will update this comment once I get the entire end-to-end working.